# How to concat two SCSS and CSS Source Maps

Tags: source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I am using sass to generate a source map which is output to a file. Then I generate a sourcemap for another CSS file using PostCSS. I am trying to concat both sourcemaps using applySourceMap in this sourcemap node module but it does work https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/blob/master/lib/source-map/source-map-generator.js

Does anyone know how to easily concat two source map files together?

Comment: The silence is deafening